# Combination Forecast - Which models to pick?

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, model

Combination Forecasting can be produced by simply averaging different forecasts or employing more complex techniques (see Makridakis, 1989; De Gooijer and Hyndman, 2006; Goodwin, 2009; Pesaran and Pick, 2011). The major principle of forecast averaging is simply by computing the average of two forecasts for the forecasting period.

I plan to do a combination forecast for real estate cycle prediction. As you can see above I read a lot of literature about it, but cannot yet decide, which models I choose to implement in R?

Any recommendation, on which factors a combination forecast can be decided?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Take a look at Diebold's [new forecasting textbook](http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/Teaching221/Forecasting.pdf) chapter 12.5 where he shows why a simple average of forecasts is often quite close to optimality. There you will find conditions under which you may just use a simple average and when you may want to do something more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Folklore among forecasters is (to my knowledge) that it is usually empirically better to combine "very different" models. So instead of combining [all possible exponential smoothing forecasts](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207006000392), it may be better to combine an exponential smoothing forecast, an ARIMA forecast (noting that some ARIMA and smoothing algorithms are more-or-less equivalent), a neural network forecast, a simple benchmark and a judgmental forecast. Or, in your case where smoothing is likely not very good for real estate cycle prediction, use different econometric models, a neural network and a number of different analysts' judgmental forecasts. However, I can't back this folklore up with references.

It seems like a simple unweighted combination, possibly after trimming or winsorizing point forecasts, may already be pretty hard to beat by more complex weighting schemes ([Kolassa, 2011](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207010001032) - note shameless self-promotion - and [Claeskens et al., 2016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2015.12.005) on the "forecast combination puzzle"). If you include judgmental forecasts, it may even be hard to determine weights for weighting schemes, since judgmental forecasts don't come with information criteria, in-sample fits, degrees of freedom and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions, I would answer them seperately:

- I plan to do a combination forecast for real estate cycle prediction.
  As you can see above I read a lot of literature about it, but cannot
  yet decide, which models I choose to implement in R?

  - Forecasting cycle is one of the most complex tasks for any forecasters. There is no general model that one could recommend for your specific problem. As [Armstrong](http://www.forecastingprinciples.com/files/standardshort.pdf) notes in his article **NOT** to forecast cycles as they are stochastic in nature and lack predictability or `unless  you know (e.g., based on contractual relationships or on physical or biological laws) that cycles will occur and have good knowledge about timing.` See also this [article by same author (p14)](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1179&context=marketing_papers). You could try forecasting by analogue. simple illustrative example follows. See below the picture from Japanese real estate bubble analogues with US home price bubble  (Source: Signal and Noise by Nate Silver). Coincidentally this is similar to what you are asking about real estate cycle. The above 2 article also have excellent information on combining forecasts.

[image]

- Any recommendation, on which factors a combination forecast can be decided?

  - In general combining forecasts works very well. I would not stop recommending the [article by Armstrong](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1005&context=marketing_papers) on combining forecast that provides general and excellent  guidance for forecasting practitioners. This would supplement Diebolds excellent chapter on combining forecast techniques that @RichardHardy has referenced. No researchers that I know of, has summarized extensive research on combining forecasts like Armstrong. Below is  a screenshot summary of the article. I'm including this because sometimes the link to the article can be broken, and it might not be useful for future readers.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: "I have read some where (but unable to find the source) that say NOT to forecast cycles as they are stochastic in nature and lack predictability.", I would really appreciate if you would be able to find the source. Thank you very much for your highly interesting answer!!!

Comment: yes, I found the source and have updated the answer.